# Javascript File Upload and Display in Table

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do a file upload with javascript, and on the next page display the content. I'm trying to upload a .csv file and display the .csv content in a table on the following page.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with JavaScript (inside the browser) alone. You need a backend to catch the uploaded CSV file and send it back to the browser for rendering.